# ClassDefNot Found & ClassNotFoundException in java Netbeans YAJTL

Tags: java, netbeans, noclassdeffounderror, classnotfoundexception

> ```
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mlawrie/yajtl/TUIOEvent
>   at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
>   at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2531)
>   at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:2774)
>   at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1663)
>   at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.getMainMethod(LauncherHelper.java:494)
>   at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:486)
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mlawrie.yajtl.TUIOEvent
>   at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
>   at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
>   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>   at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
>   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
>   at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
>   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
>   ... 6 more
> Exception in thread "main" Java Result: 1
> BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1 second)
> ```

I am trying to use the TUIO library for multitouch for java in my application. I( am using netbeans so i added the JAR files as Library files in Project Manager. I dont know why i am getting the above error.
The Library is [here](https://github.com/mlawrie/YAJTL--Yet-another-Java-TUIO-Library)

And my code is

```
package multitouch1;

import java.net.SocketException;
import com.mlawrie.yajtl.TUIOCursor;
import com.mlawrie.yajtl.TUIOEvent;
import com.mlawrie.yajtl.TUIOReceiver;



class Abc implements TUIOEvent
{
    @Override
            public void moveCursorEvent(TUIOCursor c) {
                System.out.println("Move cursor: " + c);
            }

            @Override
            public void newCursorEvent(TUIOCursor c) {
                System.out.println("New cursor: " + c);
            }

            @Override
            public void removeCursorEvent(TUIOCursor c) {
                System.out.println("Remove cursor: " + c);
            }
}
public class MultiTouch1 {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     * @throws java.net.SocketException
     * @throws java.lang.InterruptedException
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) throws SocketException, InterruptedException {
        TUIOReceiver tuio = new TUIOReceiver(800,600);

        TUIOEvent myEventHandler = new Abc();

        tuio.setHandler(myEventHandler);

        while (true) {
            //Do some stuff
            Thread.sleep(1000);
                        System.out.println("HEY123");
        }
    }

}
```

I just started it but it aint working from the start.

**Edit::**

Do i need the source files(.java) for including it as library?
 I added the main .java files in the classpath, and this error is now gone.
But a library which is used by this library, i.e I am using YAJTL and it uses JavaOSC. Now i have included the JavaOSC Jar file. When i downloaded the JavaOSC files from github, it seems that it might have updated and certain classes arent there, and the packaging is done differently. 
The error i get now is

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/illposed/osc/OSCListener
    at multitouch1.MultiTouch1.main(MultiTouch1.java:41)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.illposed.osc.OSCListener
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 1 more
Java Result: 1
```

Comment: if my answer is helpful  you can select my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for this error "**java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mlawrie/yajtl/TUIOEvent**" create new package **com** in your project and copy **com** package from the downloaded github folder(find this package inside src folder) and then replace your **com** package with this **com** package.

for the next error "**java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/illposed/osc/OSCListener**" you to download **javaosc.jar** and set your classpath.

Comment: Updated with new info

Comment: @ShauryaChaudhuri no you have to add jar file containing .class files only

Comment: @ShauryaChaudhuri after downloading the code from github extract it then goto lib folder copy the jar (javaosc.jar) and paste it  to your lib folder and then set your classpath

Comment: @ShauryaChaudhuri  for this error  "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/illposed/osc/OSCListener"  add javaosc.jar to your classpath